# How to disable an argument if another is present?

Tags: python, argparse

In my script argparse there are some arguments that will conflict if another argument of opposite kind is passed. I want to disable the `--arg2` if `--arg1` is already present. Currently I haven't found any way to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [mutually exclusive group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--arg1')
group.add_argument('--arg2')
```

Only **one** argument in the group is allowed to be used.

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
>>> group.add_argument('--arg1')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--arg1'], dest='arg1', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> group.add_argument('--arg2')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--arg2'], dest='arg2', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--arg1', 'foo'])
Namespace(arg1='foo', arg2=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--arg2', 'bar'])
Namespace(arg1=None, arg2='bar')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--arg1', 'foo', '--arg2', 'bar'])
usage: PROG [-h] [--arg1 ARG1 | --arg2 ARG2]
PROG: error: argument --arg2: not allowed with argument --arg1
```

Comment: Getting `ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional` without any reason.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: That *is* a reason, isn't it? Make sure your options are optional; e.g. do not *require* that the user specify a value.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required for what makes an option required

Comment: @SantoshKumar: *positional* arguments may also be required; make sure you use `-` or `--` in the name(s) for your arguments.

Comment: The big problem is I don't want to use `-` or `--`. It is what I'm using for publicity.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: Without `-` or `--` you have *positional* arguments and then you **cannot distinguish** between one positional argument or another, if either one is optional. A mutual exclusive group **makes no sense** for positional parameters.

Comment: I can't get the argument by `args.arg1`, All I am getting is `arg1` itself.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post a *new* question then. I can't help out without seeing code and comments are not the place to hash this out.